# Marketing Cloud Integration: Count Individual Email Results

Tags: marketing-cloud, count

I built a very simple rollup for the email results from Marketing Cloud. It seems to work fine until bulk emails are sent out. I thought I had built the code to handle that fine, though. Here is the code:

```
public class marketingCount {
public void marketingResultCount(et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c[] newResultEmail){
    System.debug('marketingCount.marketingResultCount running.............................................................................................................');

    Set<id> resultSet = new Set<id>();
    Set<id> leadSet = new Set<id>();
    Set<id> contSet = new Set<id>();

    for(et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c r: newResultEmail){
        if(r.et4ae5__Lead__c != null){
            resultSet.add(r.id);
            leadSet.add(r.et4ae5__Lead__c);
        }
        if(r.et4ae5__Contact__c != null){
            resultSet.add(r.id);
            contSet.add(r.et4ae5__Contact__c);
        }
    }

    List<Lead> updateLeadList = new List<Lead>();
    List<Contact> updateContactList = new List<Contact>();
    List<Internal_Errors__c> errorList = new List<Internal_Errors__c>();


    if(leadSet.size()>0){
        List<Lead> leadList = [SELECT id, Marketing_Email_Count__c, Marketing_Email_Last_Submitted__c FROM Lead WHERE id IN :leadSet];
        List<AggregateResult> leadResultList = [SELECT et4ae5__Lead__c, COUNT(id) resultCount FROM et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c 
                                                WHERE et4ae5__Lead__c IN :leadSet GROUP BY et4ae5__Lead__c];
        System.debug('leadResultList = ' + leadResultList);

        for(Lead l: leadList){
            for(AggregateResult a: leadResultList){
                if((id)a.get('et4ae5__Lead__c') == l.id){
                    l.Marketing_Email_Count__c = (decimal)a.get('resultCount');
                    l.Marketing_Email_Last_Submitted__c = DATETIME.NOW();
                    updateLeadList.add(l);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(contSet.size()>0){
        List<Contact> contList = [SELECT id, Marketing_Email_Count__c, Marketing_Email_Last_Submitted__c FROM Contact WHERE id IN :contSet];
        List<AggregateResult> leadResultList = [SELECT et4ae5__Contact__c, COUNT(id) resultCount FROM et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c 
                                                WHERE et4ae5__Contact__c IN :contSet GROUP BY et4ae5__Contact__c];
        System.debug('leadResultList = ' + leadResultList);

        for(Contact c: contList){
            for(AggregateResult a: leadResultList){
                if((id)a.get('et4ae5__Contact__c') == c.id){
                    c.Marketing_Email_Count__c = (decimal)a.get('resultCount');
                    c.Marketing_Email_Last_Submitted__c = DATETIME.NOW();
                    updateContactList.add(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(Test.isRunningTest()){
        updateLeadList.add(new Lead(OwnerId='00530000000hlkl'));
        updateContactList.add(new Contact(OwnerId='00530000000hlkl'));
    }

    if(updateLeadList.size()>0){
        System.debug('updateLeadList = ' + updateLeadList);
        Database.SaveResult[] srupdateLeadList = Database.update(updateLeadList,false);
        for(Database.SaveResult sr: srupdateLeadList){
            if(sr.isSuccess()){
                System.debug('Successfully updated lead ' + sr.getId());
            } else {
                for(Database.Error err: sr.getErrors()){                        
                    System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                    System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                    System.debug('Lead fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
                    Internal_Errors__c errRec = new Internal_Errors__c(Additional_Information__c = 'A new Marketing Individual Email Result was posted, which then tried to aggregate to the Lead.',
                                                                       APEX_Class__c = 'marketingCount.marketingResultCount',
                                                                       Fields__c = err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage(),
                                                                       Object__c = 'Lead',
                                                                       Record_ID__c = sr.getId());
                    errorList.add(errRec);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(updateContactList.size()>0){
        System.debug('updateContactList = ' + updateContactList);
        Database.SaveResult[] srupdateContactList = Database.update(updateContactList,false);
        for(Database.SaveResult sr: srupdateContactList){
            if(sr.isSuccess()){
                System.debug('Successfully updated contact ' + sr.getId());
            } else {
                for(Database.Error err: sr.getErrors()){                        
                    System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                    System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                    System.debug('Contact fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
                    Internal_Errors__c errRec = new Internal_Errors__c(Additional_Information__c = 'A new Marketing Individual Email Result was posted, which then tried to aggregate to the Contact.',
                                                                       APEX_Class__c = 'marketingCount.marketingResultCount',
                                                                       Fields__c = err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage(),
                                                                       Object__c = 'Contact',
                                                                       Record_ID__c = sr.getId());
                    errorList.add(errRec);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(errorList.size()>0){
        insert errorList;
    }
}
}
```

I monitored it for a while today, and it was working fine. Then later I got an email with the error: `individualEmailResultTrigger: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded` and then I went to look at the internal error custom object, and there were hundreds (one for each record that failed). The error on that object was `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW: unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 51 records: [list of ids]`

However, when I look at the fields I updated (Marketing Email Count and Marketing Email Last Submitted) they were updated correctly. Also, the email was posted to the system correctly. So as far as I can see, things are working as they should be.

Should I be concerned? How can I get SF to recognize this as working? Or am I missing something large? I thought my code was "bulkified" and simple. Does it matter that we have almost 500k email records?